# How to access /var/www/www.mysite.com/htdocs from home folder

Tags: wininet

Currently connecting to a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server from a Windows pc using WinInet.Dll.

The root folder on the server is the 'home' folder whereas the required `folders/files` are situated at `/var/www/www.mysite.com/htdocs/`.

Can retrieve directory listings, upload, download etc from subfolders of the 'home' folder but unable to determine a path to the required `folders/files`.

The uploading, downloading etc will be done via a Windows app that automatically and periodically updates the websites on the server.

One alternative would be to place the websites, etc in subfolders of the home folder.

Alternatively, please advise suitable path(s)?

Comment: Issue resolved. There was a typo in the path, '/var/...' Thanks Fahad for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use sudo if you don't have connected with root user to access those files/folders. I don't know about Winlnet.dll , but to connect Ubuntu server you can use Putty/Kitty or other similar.